# Repo sync hangs at 96% (Orangefox Recovery)

Tags: android, git, freeze, repo

I have been trying to sync the sources for Orangefox Recovery Project to build it for an old device I have. However, syncing the repos hangs at 96% every time, although it is a different repo sometimes not always the same one it freezes on. I have tried for a different branch of the same manifest and it finishes, so my question here would be is there a way to find out exactly where it is failing and isolate that repo? And then I could clone it manually after. Or whatever other way of finding the issue/forcing it finish it regardless of connectivity. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for that @ElpieKay I didn't even notice that option for sync. I saw that it was literally just taking forever to sync a large repo (~1G) on a slow connection ( around 500-800 KB/s on that specific repo ). I let it sit for a while and came back to a successful sync.

Comment: Also, I tried this with another recovery project having the same issue ( PitchBlack ) to find this. I went back to OrangeFox to test that one and it was actually pointing to the wrong location for some of its repos. I had to manually edit the fox.xml manifest to point to the right "vendor" and "bootable/recovery" repos and got it going. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `repo --trace sync -j1`.

`--trace` prints verbosely. `-j1` ensures only 1 job is run so that logs of different repos won't overlap.